# GWT: JsonpRequestBuilder cache URL issue with IE

Tags: internet-explorer, gwt, caching

I used JsonpRequestBuilder to excute url on another site. Follow my code:

```
public void execute() {
    JsonpRequestBuilder jsonp = new JsonpRequestBuilder();
    jsonp.requestObject(url, new AsyncCallback<JavaScriptObject>() {
        public void onFailure(Throwable throwable) {
        }

        public void onSuccess(JavaScriptObject jso) {
            JsArray<AdminSessionData> entries = asStartArrayOfResultData(jso);
            AdminSessionData entry = entries.get(0);
            if (entry.getSuccess()) {
                eventBus.fireEvent(new LogoutEvent());
            }
        }
    });
}
```

My code run well on Chrome and FireFox but I have issue with IE.
With IE, the first execute time run well but with the second time, the url can't be executed because the IE cache this result by url from first running time.
Do you see this issue? Please tell me your suggestions. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Are you running under devMode? Have you tested in ProdMode?

What can you see if you take a look into the network console from IE?

Are you positive about the cache, because that code is quite common...

Comment: …and the URL changes for each request!

Answer (score 0):

Jsonp uses script-tags, meaning that it does GET requests to the server.

Traditionally IE has cached GET requests even when the request has a query-string, so the normal workaround is to change the query-string in each request.

But gwt changes the callback parameter each time you create a new `JsonpRequest` because it creates a new temporary callback function which a unique name, so you would not have any problem unless you reuse the `JsonpRequest`.

The safest thing you could do to force the request, is to change the service url adding a random parameter, something like that:

```
  String sendUrl = (url.contains("?") ? "&" : "?") + 
           "foo=" + Duration.currentTimeMillis()
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Changing url request is solution for this issue. I have already fixed it.